Ollama on Colab using Xterm is too slow and froze
I tried using Ollama on Colab using Xterm
!pip -q install colab-xterm
%load_ext colabxterm
%xterm

After launching xterm, terminal popped up in the cell.
Then, I installed Ollama by running curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh and proceed to run ollama and install model by ollama serve & ollama pull gemma2
Then few lines showed up and suddenly froze. How can I fix this?
`
